# Что делать если против моего вопроса проголосовали без указания причин?

Tags: обсуждение, вопросы, голоса-против

Ситуация, думаю, типичная: я задаю вопрос на ru.stackoverflow.com, через некоторое время у него появляется -2 голоса и один человек голосует за закрытие. Ни единого комментария под вопросом не оставлено. Я ещё несколько раз перечитываю свой вопрос, пытаясь понять, почему же он "Не отражает стремления разобраться, непонятен или не несёт пользы". Однако, с моей точки зрения, вопрос полностью соответствует всем правилам.

Вопрос: что делать в таком случае? Можно ли каким-то образом обратиться за помощью к некоему эксперту, чтобы тот (или вообще кто-либо) объяснил мне, что с моим вопросом не так и как мне можно его улучшить (ну или, по крайней мере, каких ошибок не совершать, задавая следующие вопросы)?

Речь идёт конкретно об [этом](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1015156/344284) вопросе.

Comment: Не голосовал и не минусовал, но оставил вам комментарий

Answer (score 1):

*Это лишь предположение:

Возможно, что вы описываете проблему достаточно обобщенно. Желательно прикладывать код где у вас все работает, а где нет.

Так же возможно, что проблема тривиальна и является основой работы на* `c++`

*На вопрос "что делать", могу порекомендовать переформулировать вопрос, приложить более подробную информацию и задать максимально конкретизированные вопросы.*

---

*Отступление: Так же как вы можете задавать вопрос по правилам сообщества, голосующие могут ставить оценки вашим вопросам, что тоже не запрещено вышеупомянутыми правилами.*

Comment: На Ваше предположение вынужден ответить отрицательно. Я описал вопрос настолько подробно, насколько я сам смог в нём разобраться. Вопрос, по сути, в том и состоит, что я не могу определить причины возникновения ошибки. И от кода это явно не зависит.

Comment: @V-Mor - это ваше право, в том то все и дело, я ничего не утверждал.